# React package but no named import showing

Tags: reactjs, npm, package

I am creating a react component package.
I am exporting the components in a index.js file which is compiled to a index.min.js file once i build it using `rollup`.

But the problem is once i install the package and tried to import, vs code is not showing me the named imports as in `import {A} from 'a-package'`

What's i am missing?

**EDIT**

```
import React from 'react'

import a from './components/A'
import b from './components/B'

export const A = (props) => return (<a {...props} />)
export const B = (props) => return (<b {...props} />)
```

Comment: Have you added `export default A;` in your component file?

Comment: I actually added export const rather than export default, because of multiple components

Comment: named import needs curly brackets rights? There is also a B inside the package, so if i want to import both `A` and `B` i can use import {A,B} from 'a-package'

Comment: can you please share your component file or provide a CodeSandbox link ? Just to see how you have structured.

Comment: I have included the main file or the entry file into my pakcage above

Comment: But you said that you are accessing components like this : `import {A , B} from 'common-package' `
Here it's :
` import a from './components/A' ; import b from './components/B' `
I am assuming this is your parent component and {a, b} are your child components

Comment: Yea, once the package is published into npm

Comment: Try something like this: `import * as moment from 'moment' ` with your component package to access.
Alternative: use `require('../components/a") `.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue,
the issue was, since i was using rollup as a package and using the output format as `umd` rather than `cjs`

Now when i changed the format the problem is solved